# Javascript, How to change a value of an internal css class

Tags: javascript, css, stylesheet

I have an html file with and internal css style tag, which includes css classes, I'm trying to change the value of color in a class called "header1", when window width becomes less than 700:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

        var width = document.body.clientWidth;

        if (width <=700){
            var hColor = document.getElementsByTagName("style").item("header1").style.color;
               alert(hColor);

        }
    </script>
```

I tried to assign the value "red" to the variable hColor, I'm getting nothing, no errors too, it's just ignoring it, tried to test it using alert, I'm getting nothing, no type, no value.

**My question is**: how to change the value of a css class in internal css style sheet using javascript?.
I researched lots of answers, found a lot about creating style tag, and changing inlince css values, but not changing the value of internal css style, I found some in JQuery, I'm new to javascript, and I don't know JQuery, is this possible in javascript?

Here's the relevant piece of HTML:

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
```

```
<head>

    <style type="text/css" name="myStyle">

        body {

            margin:0%;
            padding:0%;
            background-color:#c9d2d9;

        }

        .div {
            width:75%;
            height:auto;
            margin:2em auto;

        }

        .nested-div{
            width:100%;
            height:auto;
            margin:2em auto;
        }

        .header1{
            width:100%;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
            color: aquamarine;


        }

    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var width = document.body.clientWidth;

        if (width <=700){
            var hColor = document.styleSheets[0].rules;
            alert(hColor[0].slectorText);

        }
    </script>

</head>

<!--------------------------------------------- BODY ---------------------------------------------->

<body>

    <div class="div">


        <div class="nested-div">

            <h1 class="header1">                
                 Some Text
            </h1>
```

Comment: Please add your (relevant piece of) HTML

Comment: Forget JavaScript. Just use CSS. (See the second of the duplicate questions).

Comment: I tried getElementsById, getElementsByTagName, none has work, as I said I'm new to javascript.

Comment: You should read into media queries in css: https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/CSS/Media_Queries
You can change the style of elements in respect to screen resolution

Comment: Added relevant HTML, The second duplicate is for external css

Comment: Is it better to use external css, or may be inline?

Comment: @Bellian is there an English version of this site?

Comment: OK, I guess this is as far as I can get to, thank you all for the suggestions.

Comment: oops.. sorry.. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: @Bellian thank you, this is the result I was looking for, I can't answer my own question, so if you have the time to put this as an answer I'll accept it.